# Ubuntu GNU/Linux AMD graphics card issue

Tags: ubuntu, debian, graphics-card, fglrx

when I bought my dell laptop, it came with Ubuntu 12.04 lts, but I removed it and installed windows 8.1 (now 10) on uefi
 my story is: whenever I install any debian/Ubuntu distro, I use the open-source ATI driver (btw my graphics cards are AMD Radeon HD 8850/R9 M200x and Intel HD Graphics 4400 I guess) which is well and all, but I want the fglrx/-updates.
 so I install it and next boot I open amd catalyst control center and when I want to edit vsync value (tearing :'() it's greyed out and it tears like crazy and a lot of options are hidden and not enabled, like the switch for battery saving and max performance

Looked and searched everywhere for this issue/bug/whatever and I cant find the fix or help needed

ANY help would be appreciated..

Comment: Don't use fglrx if the system work well with open source drivers, especially in a laptop.

Comment: Any error message in `/var/log/Xorg*`?